# N: Ignoring file 'logstash-2.2.x' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Tags: elastic-stack

When I try to install logstash, this happens:

```
root@ip-x:/home/ubuntu# sudo apt-get install logstash
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   logstash is already the newest version.
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 41 not upgraded.
>   N: Ignoring file 'logstash-2.2.x' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
>   N: Ignoring file 'logstash-2.2.x' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

After this issue I can't install update and remove. Problem is logstash package is malfunctioned. So the solution is removing that package.

Here are the steps I done:

```
#cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d

#rm -rf logstash-2.2.x(error package name)

#sudo apt-get update
```